# How to set component attributes?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

In my footer component, I have the following:

```
<aura:attribute name="buttons" type="Aura.Component[]" />
```

... where I inject the buttons I want on the footer.

However I need to set onclick actions for these buttons. What's the right way to do this?

I suppose it is correct for my footer component to hold these actions and execute them. If so, how do I set the onclick attribute of those buttons on the footer's controller?

I've tried:

```javascript
let buttons = component.get('v.buttons')

for (var button of buttons) {
    button.set('v.onclick', 'c.clickHandler')
}
```

... to no avail.

Comment: is this related to a custom aura template component needed in Experience cloud (community) ?

Answer (score 5):

You have to pass in a reference to the callback, and use addEventHandler, as in:

```
button.addEventHandler('eventName', component.getReference('c.clickHandler'));
```

The component must have an `aura:registerEvent` that matches `eventName` in order to make this work.

You can read more in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_handler.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, addEventHandler just handles an event that is fired. I'm stuck on the firing part. See, I'm providing lightning:buttons from a parent to a child component and these buttons come without an onclick handler because only the child component has/knows the method to be run when those buttons are clicked. I don't know how to add an onclick handler to those buttons.

Comment: Also, I noticed you said `button.addEventHandler...` but the link you attached only shows examples using `cmp.addEventHandler...`. When I try the former in my sandbox I get `button.addEventHandler is not a function`. I addEventHandler after everything has rendered.

Comment: @parsa_047Fletcher My apologies for missing your comments. `button` is just a placeholder. You can attach an event to any object you want that is a custom component. Standard HTML elements will still use addEventListener, in which case you specify a function (normally kept in a helper).

Answer (score 4):

I first want to suggest to use LWC more than Aura. Aura is older and more or less deprecated or in the path to be. Also, in LWC, event handling (and almost everything) will be closer to standard javascript thus help will be easier to find.

Documentation given by @sfdcfox is correct and even more interesting is [Handling Component Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_handling_intro.htm).

So in Aura you need these steps:

- Create a custom component event
- Fire that custom event from your button component
- Handle the custom event from the footer component

I hope this helps, feel free to comment.

Comment: It's not deprecated, per se, it still has specific purposes that LWC doesn't fill (e.g. Lightning Apps), but I agree in general one should use LWC when possible.

Comment: That's why I said "more or less" and "in the path to be". Knowing Salesforce it might take 5-10 years looking at how long they took to remove classic from new orgs (and it is still present in old orgs). Obviously we can't completely avoid it today and we usually only have aura components as wrapper / proxy for LWC to ease the transition when possible. That's not the topic here so I think we should focus on the problem exposed.

Comment: "Archived" would be the proper term here imo. not deprecated, still supported, no longer developed.